Why the normalization of an integral curve induces isomorphic function fields?
Here a curve over the field $k$ is a separated $k$-scheme $C$ of finite type that is equi-dimensional of dimension $1$. In the Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Vol. 2, Example 26.13, He states that for an integral curve $C$, and its normalization $\pi :C' \to C$ ( if needed I will upload definition of the normalization ), $\pi $ is a finite morphism ( by Corollary 12.52 ( Vol. 1) ) and hence $K(C) = K(C')$ by definition. And why the finiteness of $\pi$ implies $K(C) = K(C')$? To show this several properties of normalization may needed?
My first attempt is as follows : take an affine open neighborhood $V= \operatorname{Spec}A \subseteq C$ of the generic point $\eta \in C$. Note that since $C$ is an integral scheme and $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is nonempty , $K(C) = \mathrm{Frac}(A)$. Since $\pi : C' \to C$ is finite, $\pi^{-1}(V) = \mathrm{Spec}B$ is also affine and the induced homomorphism $A \to B$ is a finite ring homomorphism. Note also that $K(C')= \mathrm{Frac}(B)$ ( $\because$ Since $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ is nonempty, since it contains the generic point of $C'$ ; the normalization morphism $\pi$ is dominant ). And note that $\dim A = \dim \mathrm{Spec}A = \dim C =1 = \dim C' = \dim \mathrm{Spec}B=\dim B$ ( $\because$ Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book, Theorem 5.22 -(3) ). From these data can we show $K(C) = \mathrm{Frac}(A) \cong \mathrm{Frac}(B)=K(C')$? This is a point that I stuck. Do we need any more information?  Is there any hints to breakthrough this difficulty? What should I catch?
EDIT : After some investigation of other reference, I think that the equality $K(C)=K(C')$ can be derived from some several properties of normalizaiton. I don't know if I can prove it with just the finiteness of $\pi$. Here's the relevant facts that I found:

Proposition 12.43 ( Gortz, Wedhorn, Alebraic Geometry, Vol.1. ) Let $X$ be an integral scheme, let $L$ be an algebraic extension of $K(X)$, and let $\pi :X' \to X$ be the normalization of $X$ ( his book p.343 ). Then

$(1)$ The scheme $X'$ is integral and normal, and $K(X')=L$.
$(2)$ The morphism $\pi$ is integral and surjective and $\dim X' = \dim X$.
$(3)$ Let $U \subseteq X$ be a non-empty open subscheme. Then the restriction $\pi^{-1}(U)\to U$ is the normalization of $U$ in $L$.
$(4)$ Assume that $X=\mathrm{Spec}A$ is affine and let $S\subseteq A$ be the multiplicative set of nonzero elements. Then $X' =\mathrm{Spec}A'$ with
$$ A'= \{ b\in L ; b \operatorname{is integral over} A \}$$ and $S^{-1}A'=L$.


And use the $(1)$. I understood its proof and I will upload its proof later if needed.

No, $\pi: C_1 \to C_2$ is finite doesn't imply $K(C_1) = K(C_2)$. Just take $C_1=C_2=\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and the morphism $x \mapsto x^2$, then the associated extension of fields $K(C_2) \to K(C_1)$ is of degree 2.

O.K. Can you explain more friendly why the extension is of degree $2$? What is explicit form of the ring homomorphism $K(C_2) \to K(C_1)$?

Both function fields would be isomorphic to $k(x)$ and the map $k(x) \to k(x)$ will be given by $x \mapsto x^2$. The image is $k(x^2) \subset k(x)$ and that extension is of degree 2.

O.K. And perhaps, the map $\varphi : A:=k[x] \to B:=k[x]$, $x \mapsto x^2$ is finite ring homomorphism? What would be generator of $B$ over $A$? ${1,x}$?

Exactly, every polynomial $f \in k[x]$ can be written as $f = p + xq$ with $p,q \in k[x^2]$ just by separating the even and odd monomials of $f$.

O.K. I got it. I learned a lot. Thanks for proposing counter example !

The bottom line is that the function field is a birational invariant. The normalization map $\pi: C' \to C$ is an isomorphism away from the preimage of the finitely many singular points of $C$, hence it is a birational equivalence. Thus $\pi$ has degree $1$, so the function field extension $K(C') \supseteq K(C)$ has degree $1$, hence $K(C') = K(C)$. I think they mean $K(C) = K(C')$ "by definition" of the normalization of an integral scheme, but I'd have to read the definition of normalization in Chapter 12 more closely.
